# Why is a state in ReactJS changing to 'undefined' when I reload the page. I am using MobX for state management

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have a component that gets state data from a store. But when I reload the page, the state changes to undefined.

```
const PartnerDetails = (props) => {
 const { store: { partnerStore } } = useContext(AuthContext);
const [usePersonalDetails, setUsePersonalDetails] = useState(
        partnerStore.partner && partnerStore.partner.usePersonalDetails); //boolean

return (
    <>
          {console.log(partnerStore,'load')}
          {console.log(usePersonalDetails,'load')}
         <CopyDetailsItem
             label="Set personal details as partner details"
             text="Use personal details"
             state={usePersonalDetails}
             toggle={//changeHandler}
             name="copyDetails"/>
    </>)

};
PartnerDetails.propTypes = {
    history: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any),
};

export default PartnerDetails;
```

This component is a page I can navigate to by clicking on a button.
When I navigate to the page, the data is fetched by the `partnerStore` and the `console.log` lines log the data as-is from the store.
However when I click on the reload button on a browser (Chrome), `console.log(partnerStore,'The partner store')` shows the data from the partner store **BUT** `console.log(usePersonalDetails)` says `undefined`. Inspecting the logged data from `partnerStore` clearly shows that `usePersonalDetails` is defined

How can I fix this?

Comment: check  `partnerStore.partner.usePersonalDetails` property exists?

Comment: Yeah @NageshwarReddyPandem `partnerStore.partner.usePersonalDetails` exists

Comment: replace partnerStore.partner.usePersonalDetails with partnerStore?.partner?.usePersonalDetails ?? false;